Excel: The number of days a name appears without counting multiple occurrences on the same day
Suppose we have the following table:



date
period
name




1/5/2024
1
SAM


1/5/2024
2
SAM


1/5/2024
3
JHONE


2/5/2024
1
SAM


2/5/2024
1
JHONE


2/5/2024
2
JHONE


2/5/2024
3
ROB


3/5/2024
1
JHONE



I want to count the number of days a name appears without counting multiple occurrences on the same day
SAM       = 2 days
JHONE     = 3 days
ROB       = one day



You can always load your table to the "Data Model" within Excel and create a simple Pivot Table.

And if you don't have access to GROUPBY yet:
=LET(u,DROP(UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(A2:C9,1,3)),,1),
     x,UNIQUE(u),
HSTACK(x,MAP(x,LAMBDA(y,SUM(N(u=y))))))


If you have access to the Groupby function in Excel 365 you can try:
=LET(uniq,UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(A2:C9,{3,1})),
GROUPBY(TAKE(uniq,,1),TAKE(uniq,,-1),COUNT,0,1))



Since GROUPBY() will use ETA lambda anyways, why not just simplify this a little ;): =GROUPBY(C2:C9,A2:A9,LAMBDA(x,ROWS(UNIQUE(x))),0,0). Nice answer Tom!

Just adding an option using table (core method is the same as Tom's and P.b's above):
=LET(
names,SORT(UNIQUE(Table1[name])),
distinct_count,LAMBDA(array,ROWS(UNIQUE(array))),
dates_for_name, LAMBDA(name,FILTER(Table1[date],Table1[name]= name)),
fmt,LAMBDA(n,TEXT(n,"[=1] ""single day""; 0 ""days""")),
HSTACK(names,
MAP(names, LAMBDA(name,  fmt(distinct_count(dates_for_name(name)))))
))

GROUPBY is not yet available under Mac Excel yet; but using it under Windows:
(For ease of use define distinct_row and dates_count_formatted first)

Then use
GROUPBY(Table1[name],Table1[date],dates_count_formatted,0,0)

Result showing both options:

